# What is the "standard trace inner product"

Tags: matrices, inner-products, trace

I'm trying to understand some text in the paper below (section 2. beginning of page 3). The text states that  <·> denotes the standard
trace inner product, but I can't seem to determine what the "standard trace inner product" is of these two matrices which are not necessarily square.

*Yuan, Xiaoming; Yang, Junfeng*, [**Sparse and low-rank matrix decomposition via alternating direction method**](http://www.ybook.co.jp/online2/oppjo/vol9/p167.html), Pac. J. Optim. 9, No. 1, 167-180 (2013). [ZBL1269.90061](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1269.90061).

Comment: $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr} (A^*B)$. It is the inner product that is associated with the Frobenious norm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set $<A, B> = \operatorname{tr} (A^*B) \textrm { or }\operatorname{tr}({}^t AB)$ whether your matrices have complex or real coefficient (the conjugate gives the transposition in the real case) and it is well definied as soon as $A^*B \textrm { or }{}^t AB$ is square.